# bootstrap fa active color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

how can i set the active-color of a i with fa to #9b0722?

My HTML looks like the following:

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Topbar Navigation -->
        <ul class="loginbar pull-right">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#" title="Startseite">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>  
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="topbar-devider"></li>   
            <li><a href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li> 
            <li class="topbar-devider"></li> 
            <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><a href="tel:+497147273729"> +49 7147 273729</a></li> 
            <li class="topbar-devider"></li>   
            <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>   
        </ul>
        <!-- End Topbar Navigation -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

As simple as this:

```
i.fa{color:#9b0722}
```

if you mean on hover, then

```
i.fa:hover{color:#9b0722}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean changing the color of the icon when it's hovered, put the icon inside the anchor.

For example:

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +49 7147 273729</a>
</li>
```

Then in your CSS then you can change the color when it's hovered like this:

```
a:hover i.fa {
    color:#9b0722;
}
```